# Notepad++: how to automatically format JSON when opening the file

Tags: notepad++, json

I work with many JSON files.

It would be useful to **automatically** **format JSON** **when opening the file** in Notepad++.

At the moment, I'm using JSON viewer plugin. I have to select the text and choose Plugin > JSON viewer > Format JSON or use a shortcut.

Any advice?

Comment: why downvoting?

Comment: Isn't this the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560464/how-to-reformat-json-in-notepad There are several others. But installing JSTool and running its JSFormat (Ctrl-Alt-M) is what worked for me.

Comment: @BobStein I want the automatic formatting when opening the file...

Comment: Ah, that does make this question unique. Huh, some kind of **Pretty Print button** next to the Word Wrap button could be useful in other languages too (HTML, CSS, ...). And if the button stayed pressed, as Word Wrap does, that could give you your automatic feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23571/double-click-on-a-json-file-notepad-should-auto-run-the-well-json-formating.
There is a full answer there, in notepad++ community.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.